# SAS: Reading Date field with one informat which it is saved in a different date format

Tags: sas

I was trying to read a date field using date. informat from a SAS dataset. This dataset was created using a date format of mmddyy10. I thought I will get incorrect results when I realized that I was trying to read the date with incorrect format than what it was saved in the SAS dataset.

Could someone clear me if it is a weird behaviour or SAS is intelligent to recognize that date. or mmddyy10. both represents the same date?

```
DATA WORK.BOOKED_DEALER_TRANSACTIONS; 
  INFILE DEALER_RECORDS DSD; 
  INPUT @10 STATUS $15. 
        @26 TRANSACTION_REQ_DT MMDDYY10. 
        @ 46 PROCESS_DT MMDDYY10. 
        @63 DLR_NM $30. 
        @119 PROCESS_TIME TIME 
  ; 
  WHERE ORDER_STATUS = 'CONFIRMED_ORDERS';
run;
```

Comment: Hello Naga, would you be able to post example of your data and code for  what you already tried?

Comment: I think you don't understand how SAS dates work, but I'll wait to answer until you give a working example so can be sure I understand what you mean.  If you need help constructing one we're happy to do so.

Comment: DATA WORK.BOOKED_DEALER_TRANSACTIONS;
INFILE DEALER_RECORDS DSD;
INPUT   <at>10  STATUS    $15. 
  <at>26  TRANSACTION_REQ_DT  MMDDYY10. 
 <at> 46  PROCESS_DT   MMDDYY10. 
 <at>63  DLR_NM    $30. 
 <at>119 PROCESS_TIME   TIME. 
.
.
.
;
WHERE ORDER_STATUS = 'CONFIRMED_ORDERS'
run;  This is the way the data step is creating a orders SAS dataset. This I am reading in another PROC SQL but reading the dates and comparing it with another date which is saved in date. format. I am not getting any error (also result is coming perfectly fine) which for me is really wondering how it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date values in SAS (when saved correctly) are stored as an integer, namely the integer number of days since 1/1/1960.  So today is `20230`, for example.

Then formats tell SAS what it should look like when printed neatly; and informats tell SAS how to translate neatly printed dates to this number.  In your example, `mmddyy10.` is an informat which tells SAS to take `05/22/2015` and turn it into `20230`.

You're welcome to then compare something with DATE9. format to this date value: because both will be stored as integers.  How they look on the screen is relevant to humans, but the integer is relevant to SAS.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Joe. As per this I understand that if there are 2 dates say in SAS dataset A (format saved as date.) and dataset B (format saved as mmddyy10.) then as internally they are saved as integers I can do any comparisons without worrying about formats and can also apply date functions like INTCK.

Comment: If they're saved as real dates - yes.  (Of course, if they're character variables, all of this goes out the window.)

Comment: Awesome, got you. Thank you very much Joe